# What OpenCart plugins are available or in the works for Bitcoin transactions?

Tags: transactions, shopping-cart-interface

I've installed the [walletbit](https://walletbit.com/) module in my installation of OpenCart but any others would be appreciated, especially if someone's working on MTGox/Tradehill integration! Is there much in the works or anything I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for bitpay (bit-pay.com) that can be found [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3119&path=20).

Bitpay allows merchants to accept bitcoins but to be paid in dollars which can be very convenient for merchants who are interested in trying out Bitcoin but might not yet be convinced of its greatness.

Comment: on their website sign up page it says "Bit-pay is now available to businesses in the United States!" - does this mean it's unavailable to the rest of the world?

Answer (score 2):

There is also this [Bitcoin for Opencart](http://codecanyon.net/item/bitcoin-for-opencart/8927110) module; I have been using it and it works very great as it also protect you against double spending and is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Opencart-bitcoin-payment-module

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=bitcoin

So go this link and get your desired module.